# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in Node App

Tags: node.js

I'm building a crypto tracker in node. I have a list of addresses in the Wallet collection. I'm wanting to perform an API call to ethplorer for each address. I'm getting the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and also `req.next is not a function`. I'm confused because I'm not even using a req.next anywhere.

Any idea what's causing this error?

```
app.get('/ethplorer', function(req, res) {
  const rp = require('request-promise');
  Wallet.find({}).then(function(wallets) {
    var allData = [];
    wallets.forEach(function(w) {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET', 
        url: `https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/${w.address}`,
        qs: {
          'apiKey': 'aaa'
        },
        json: true       
      };
      rp(requestOptions).then(response => {
        allData.push(response);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
      res.render('ethereum', {user: req.user, eth: allData});
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`allData` is not going to be populated, nor should you do `res.render` in a loop

Rewritten to use async/await, avoid `then()` callbacks its messy

```js
const rp = require('request-promise')

app.get('/ethplorer', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      qs: {
        'apiKey': 'aaa'
      },
      json: true
    }

    let allData = []
    for (let wallet of await Wallet.find({})) {
      try {
        allData.push(await rp({
          ...requestOptions,
          url: 'https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/' + wallet.address
        }))
      } catch (_) {}
    }

    res.render('ethereum', {
      user: req.user,
      eth: allData
    })
  } catch (e) {
    next(e)
  }
})
```